# GWT plugin for Safari (Mac)

Tags: macos, gwt, safari

I am developing GWT+GAE application. In dev mode, I can successfully open the app in FF and Chrome. However, when I try to open it in Safari, I get the missing plugin window. After I click on it, it downloads the dmg which I use to install (I get the successfully installed dialog) However, when I restart Safari, I get the same result. Anybody faced a similar situation? Any workaround?

Comment: Ok. Safari 5.1 is the culprit. http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/b8827956a9b13bfb

Answer (score 0):

There is no Safari Dev Mode Plugin

I know two workarrounds:

1. Use [OmniWeb](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniweb/)
2. Use [SuperDev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html)